# Best way to validate json response in python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x, testing

I am using python 3 for functional testing of a bunch of rest endpoints.
But i cannot figure out the best way to validate the json reaponse ( verifying the type, required, missing and additional fields)

I thought of below options :
1. Writing custom code and validate the response while converting the data into python class objects. 
2. Validate using json schema .

Option 1: would be difficult to maintain and need to add separate functions to all the data models.
Option 2 : i like it. But i dont want to write schema for each endpoint in separate file/object. Is there a way to put it in a single object like we have swagger yml file. That way would be easy to maintain.

I would like to know which option is the best and if there are other better options / libraries available.

Comment: I have found json schema to be much less flexible than yaml. Often, difficult, is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been through the same process, but validating REST requests *and* responses with Java. In the end I went with JSON Schema (there's an equivalent Python implementation at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) because it was simple and powerful, and hand-crafting the validation for anything but a trivial payload soon became a nightmare. Also, reading a JSON Schema file is easier than reasoning about a long list of validation statements.

It's true you need to define the schema in a separate file, but this proved to be no big deal. And, if your endpoints share some common features you can modularise your schemas and reuse common parts. There's a good tutorial at [Understanding JSON Schema](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/index.html).